# Star data format explained

Tags: raw-data

I am looking for a formal explanation of the following star database format:

```
Akamar,f|S|A3,02:58:15.696|-44.6,-40:18:16.97|19.0,3.2,2000,0
Menkar,f|S|M2,3:02:16.8|-11.81,4:05:24|-78.76,2.54,2000,0
Mirfak,f|S|F5,03:24:19.37|24.11,49:51:40.25|-26.01,1.8,2000,0
Aldebaran,f|S|K5,4:35:55.2|62.78,16:30:35|-189.36,0.87,2000,0
Rigel,f|S|B8,5:14:32.3|1.87,-8:12:06|-0.56,0.18,2000,0
```

I know most of the values, but can anyone send me a link to the formal description?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like [XEphem](http://www.clearskyinstitute.com/xephem/)'s format of databases as described in the manual's [file format description](http://www.clearskyinstitute.com/xephem/help/xephem.html#mozTocId468501). Does the filename end in `.edb` ? That is a common extension for these sort of files. Assuming it is, then the format breaks down as (taking the first line for example):

- A name (`Akamar`)
- A "type designation" for the sort of object, in this case `f` for fixed (as opposed to orbital elements or a bound satellite)
- A subfield for the `f`ixed type indicating it's a `S`tar
- The spectral type of the star (`A3`)
- Right ascension (RA) and proper motion in RA (`02:58:15.696` and `-44.6` milliarcsec/year)
- Declination and proper motion in Dec (`-40:18:16.97` and `19.0` milliarcsec/year)
- Magnitude (brightness) of the object (`3.2`)
- Reference epoch for the proper motions (`2000.0`)

Comment: perfect answer! I had seen it once but forgotten to bookmark it. Thanks.